# Why can't I set a non-global function as a callback in Jack?

Tags: c++, jack

I'm trying to set a callback function in Jack. This is usually quite simple, using the function "jack_set_process_callback" (in the case of setting the "process" callback).

The definition in the API is this:

```
int jack_set_process_callback(jack_client_t* client, JackProcessCallback process_callback, void* arg).
```

In the example code (which has C components) the global function below is declared.

```
int process(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg){

  // do something in the callback
  return 0;
}
```

It is then set as the Jack process callback by the line:

```
jack_set_process_callback(client, process, 0)
```

.. and this compiles and works perfectly.

What I'm doing now is trying to build a class-based audio program. I'm putting all the Jack stuff inside a class imaginatively called "Sound_Module".

The definition of the function that I want to set as my callback is now a member function of this class:

```
int Sound_Module::process(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg){

  // do something in the callback
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to set this method as my callback function within the class constructor:

```
(83) jack_set_process_callback(client, process, 0)
```

but on compilation this leads to the following error:

```
sound_module.cpp:83: error: argument of type ‘int (Sound_Module::)(jack_nframes_t, void*)’ does not match ‘int (*)(jack_nframes_t, void*)’
```

I get the impression from this error message that I need to cast the callback function to something else. I've tried a few things, such as casting to the Jack type designed for callbacks with no luck - below is the line dug out of the API for "JackProcessCallback".

```
typedef int(* JackProcessCallback)(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
```

Can anyone shed any light on what this compiler error might be hinting at, or what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions are different from non-member functions because you can only call them on an object of the class type of which the function is a member.

You need to write a non-member function that delegates to the member function.  When you call `jack_set_process_callback`, you tell the library what to pass to the `void*` parameter of your callback, so you can tell it to pass back the address of the `Sound_Module` object for which you want to call the member function callback.

The non-member callback is quite simple:

```
int Sound_Module_Process_Callback(jack_nframes_t x, void* p)
{
    return static_cast<Sound_Module*>(p)->process(x);
}
```

Registered as:

```
jack_set_process_callback(client, Sound_Module_Process_Callback, this);
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. Out of interest, do you consider it bad practice to write global functions of this type in OOP C++?

Comment: No; there is nothing wrong with using non-member functions in C++ (in fact, there are lots of things wrong with overusing member functions).  You don't have a choice here, though, so you may as well use one.

Comment: Couldn't it be added as a static member function?

Answer (score 2):

It's because every member function of class has a hidden argument **this**. Instead declare the call back method as **static**.

```
error: argument of type ‘int (Sound_Module::)(jack_nframes_t, void*)’  
                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This part of the error message says it's a member function hinting the hidden argument **this**.

```
does not match ‘int (*)(jack_nframes_t, void*)’
```

And this part says it is regular C-type call back function declaration.

Instead try this -

```
 class Sound_Module {
    public:
    static int process(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg) ; 
   // This is just declaration. Provide the definition in the source file.
 };
```

Comment: you may have to specify a calling convention too.

Comment: So if the method is declared as static does that mean the "hidden argument" is no longer passed?

Comment: Just to answer my own comment based on @Kerrek_SB's answer, this hidden argument is in fact a function pointer in the case of free functions and static member functions. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

tl;dr: Member functions are not free functions. Your callback has to be a free function.

Longer answer: The set-callback function requires a *function pointer* as its callback argument. Only free functions can be turned into a function pointer. Non-static member functions are not free functions, and they cannot be turned into function pointers! The expression `&Foo::f` is a *pointer-to-member-function* (PTFM), which is an entirely different, incompatible, usually much larger type.

If your client function is fixed by a C API, then you have two possible solutions:

1. Make a static member function. Static member functions are essentially just free functions, so they do produce function pointers. In that case you're not really using the class structure and there's no statefulness (which is why you *can* do this).
2. Write a global wrapper function.

```
Sound_Module g_sm1; // global!
Sound_Module g_sm2;

int process1(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
  return g_sm1.process_firsttype(nframes, arg);
}
int process2(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
  return g_sm1.process_secondtype(nframes, arg);
}
int process3(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
  return g_sm2.process_firsttype(nframes, arg);
}
int process4(jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
  static Sound_Module s_sm;
  return s_sm.process_firsttype(nframes, arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-static member function cannot be callback, since they can be invoked only instances of the class.

I think you should be doing this:

```
int callback(jack_nframes_t nframes, void* arg)
{
    return static_cast<Sound_Module*>(arg)->process(nframes);
}
```

And define the member function `process`  as

```
int Sound_Module::process(jack_nframes_t nframes){

  // do something in the callback
  return 0;
}
```

That is, it should take one parameter only. Second parameter is not needed.

Also, you should call `jack_set_process_callback` as:

```
 jack_set_process_callback(client, callback, &soundModule);
                                           //^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is, the third argument should be the address of an instance of `Sound_Module`. It could be `this` pointer as well, if you're calling this from a member function of `Sound_Module` as:

```
void Sound_Module::SomeNonStaticMemberFunction()
{
     jack_set_process_callback(client, callback, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In your third code bracket do you mean the jack_set_process_callback should be set as:

    jack_set_process_callback(client, callback, &Sound_Module)

 since this is the global function?

Comment: @Speedy: No. `Sound_Module` is a class. I mean, an object of this class.

Answer (score -1):

A more C++ oriented approach, the key is using Jack's JackProcessCallback predefined type:

```
#include <jack/jack.h>

BaseSoundModule
{
    public:

    jack_client_t * client;

    //Use a constructor to assign a client to the class.
    BaseSoundModule( jack_client_t * external_client ){ client = external_client; }

    //Use Jack's JackProcessCallback predefined type.
    void setProcessCallback( JackProcessCallback, void * pointerArgument )
    {
        jack_set_process_callback( client, JackProcessCallback, pointerArgument );
    }

};

Metronome : public BaseSoundModule
{
    static int process_audio( jack_nframes_t nframes, void * arg )
    {
        //Note #1 at the end of this example
        Metronome * MetroPointer = ( Metronome * ) arg;

        //Call other functions inside your metronome class;
        Metronome->someotherfunc();
    }

    int someotherfunc(){ //return something. }
};
```

Then you would call this like so:

```
jack_client_t * client;

int main()
{
    Metronome Metro;

    Metronome * MetroPointer = &Metro;

    BaseSoundModule * PolyMetro = &Metro;

    PolyMetro->setProcessCallback( MetroPointer->process_audio, MetroPointer );

}
```

- Note 1: Notice that inside process_audio you also passed MetroPointer as an argument. Which means you can use other methods of the child class inside the callback.